# conv2D does not give expected Output shape

Tags: python, keras, model, conv-neural-network

I am trying to copy a model architecture. In the original model architecture, after applying **Conv2d** Output Shape is (None, 112, 112, 16) with 432 params. As shown in the image attached
[original Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf502.png)

But when I apply the conv2d output shape I am getting is (None, 225, 225, 16) with 448 params. as shown in my model image
[My model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnGm4.png)

This is the code I wrote

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, ZeroPadding2D, InputLayer, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
inputs = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = ZeroPadding2D(padding=((1,0),(1,0)))(inputs)
x = Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same")(x)
x = Dense(1500, activation="relu")(x)
x = Dense(1000, activation="relu")(x)
prediction = Dense(784, activation='softmax')(x)

model_functional = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=prediction)

model_functional.summary()
```

Comment: you didn't added stride, set the strides=(2,2)

Comment: thanks, that change the shape, but now I am getting (None, 113, 113, 16)

Comment: I want its shape (None, 112, 112, 16)

Comment: After removing padding I am getting (None, 112, 112, 16), as it should. thank you